# MULAW - Audio data is being streamed too slow

Tags: google-cloud-speech, mu-law

I have a problem with speech recognition in streaming mode. My audio source is a VoIP phone protocol (SIP), it allows you to output audio data in a format:
"encoding": "Mulaw", 
"sampleRateHertz": 8000

- When I send a new portion of data in streaming mode, an exception occurs: "Status(StatusCode=OutOfRange, Detail="Audio data is being streamed too slow. Please stream audio data approximately at real time.")"
- For verification, I wrote the data to disk in this format. After I read the data and send it in chunks in a streaming mode, it all works correctly and the result is returned.

It turns out that the error appears only in realtime. I ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I opened the session and started sending the stream there in 5-10 seconds, because of this there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Audio streaming samplerate 8000 and RecognitionConfig.setSampleRate(8000) should sync same,

e.g., if audio streamed at **8000** and RecognitionConfig.setSamplerate(**16000**) - > results Audio streamed too **slow**

if audio streamed at **41000** and RecognitionConfig.setSamplerate(**16000**) - > results Audio streamed too **fast**